# WalletConnect mobile wallets that support custom chains

Tags: metamask, wallets, walletconnect

Iam trying to test walletConnect implementaiton in my code and i can't find a fully working wallet that lets you use custom networks, i tried multiple wallets and each had their issues:

- Metamask for android doesn't receive transactions so can't be used
- AlphaWallet, always declines transactions when accepting or refusing transactions
- trust wallet doesn't let you use custom networks.
- Many other wallets have similar issues

Is there any known testing wallet on mobile that supports the walletConnect protocol and custom network ?

Comment: Problem with MetaMask it is very slow and buggy on Android and requires https for custom networks. Did you by any chance find any other test wallet for this?

Comment: Metamask actually doesn't have issue with http, but you can try alpha wallet, but all the others are not good for development.

Comment: Thank you, will give it a try! I just tried Math wallet on Android earlier today - it has wallet connect, I can configure a test network and it's lightning fast compared to MM..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for this I turned back to Metamask again, but this time i used a different web3 version of my website and that solved the issue with Metamask not taking transactions.

The thing was that some "stable" versions of web3 did not bond well with  Walletconnect protocol's provider component and resulted in no events being fired to the WC provider when using it with web3. This was fixed starting from the web3 version "1.6.1".